# Centering column names with `pander` while left justifying content

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc

I am using the `pander::pander` function to make some tables in a knitted latex document. I want the rows to be left justified and *the column names to be centered*.

```r
library(pander)
library(dplyr)

tibble(`column name` = c("long text string", "* hi")) %>% 
    pander(
      keep.line.breaks = TRUE, 
      style = 'grid', 
      missing = '', 
      split.table = Inf,
      justify = 'left'
      )
```

[image: left justified pander output]

Does the `pander` function have an argument to center column names? I am having trouble finding it in the documentation or anywhere else online.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `pandoc.table` :

```
tibble(`column name` = "long text string") %>% 
  pandoc.table()

#------------------
#   column name    
#------------------
# long text string 
#------------------
```

Comment: hmm I have a bullet point in my table, which isn't parsing correctly when I use this method -- I'll update the question to reflect that

Comment: How do you get the output to be shown as you have in your question? For me the output is just printed in the console. Do you write it in markdown and then knit the file?

Comment: yes, i've been knitting. Are you able to reproduce this example?

Comment: Yes, after going though the documents I couldn't find a way to have different alignment for column names and value.